# Residuals and an identity of the cotangent

Tags: complex-analysis

My girlfriend has a [complex analysis problem set](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/jbuethe/MP3/Blatt11.pdf) where I am stuck. The first part is:

> Let
>   $$ \cot(z) = \frac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)} $$
>   be the cotangent. Show that $\cot$ is homomorphic in $\mathbb C \setminus \pi \mathbb Z$ and has singularities of order 1 at $n \pi$ with a residue of 1.

I got that one. Since $\cos$ and $\sin$ are composed of exponential functions which are homomorphic, they are so as well. The division is a homomorphic operation as well, except if the divisor is zero. (They are allowed to the use the last statement verbatim.)

The pole $n\pi$ is inserted into $\cos(z)/\sin'(z)$, which is always 1. So the residue is indeed 1.

Now the next part is:

> Show further, that for all $z \in \mathbb C \setminus \frac\pi2\mathbb Z$ it holds:
>   $$ 2 \cot(2z) = \cot(z) + \cot\left(z + \frac\pi2\right). $$

I do see that the singularities and residues line up well:

http://chaos.stw-bonn.de/users/mu/uploads/2014-01-21/screenshot-1.png

However, I am not sure how I can show this identity. Expanding the $\cot$ into its definition and using trigonometric identities looks like a endless mess which would not get me anywhere.

What is the trick to this problem?

---

The next problem seems to be very related, so I post it in this question as well.

> Let $f$ be an odd, $\mathbb C \setminus \pi \mathbb Z$ holomorphic function with simple poles with residue 1 at integer multiples of $\pi$. Also, $f$ holds the relation
>   $$2 f(2z) = f(z) + f\left(z + \frac\pi2\right).$$
>
> Hint: Look at the function $h = f - \cot$ and use the maximum principle on a circle with radius $3\pi$ and center at 0, which states that a non-constant holomorphic function has its maximum absolute value on the boundary.

I tried a parametrisation of the circle and finding the maximum value of $h$. The circle lies exactly on a pole of both $f$ and $\cot$. So the maximum of both $f$ and $\cot$ is $\infty$. How do I know that the difference is 0? Do I have to use the Cauchy formula which gives me the value at $z$ by integrating in a circle containing $z$? If I make it of radius $\epsilon$, would I only have to take the residue into account?

Comment: Residuum = residue, not residual; ungerade = odd, not uneven.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Expanding the cot into its definition and using trigonometric identities looks like a endless mess which would not get me anywhere.

It's okay if you know how to do it:

$$\begin{align}
\cot z + \cot \left(z +\frac{\pi}{2}\right) &= \frac{\cos z}{\sin z} + \frac{\cos \left(z+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{\sin \left(z+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\\
&= \frac{\cos z}{\sin z} + \frac{-\sin z}{\cos z}\\
&= \dotsc\vphantom{\frac12}\\
&= 2\cot (2z).
\end{align}$$

I left a few steps out, some trigonometric identities are useful there.

> I tried a parametrisation of the circle and finding the maximum value of $h$. The circle lies exactly on a pole of both $f$ and $\cot$.

But they both have simple poles with the same residue, so $h = f - \cot$ is an entire function. And it is odd, and satisfies the doubling relation

$$2h(2z) = h(z) + h\left(z+\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$$

That relation is the crucial one to deduce that $h$ is constant. And since it is odd, it must be $\equiv 0$. Still, choosing a circle with radius $3\pi$ may not have been the best choice, a radius of $10$ would do equally well without passing through a pole of $f$ or $\cot$.

Comment: For the first part, I think I will manage it. For the second part: Having same poles with same residue means that the difference will have no poles? This makes some sense. Being odd implies $\equiv 0$ *once shown that it is constant*, is fine too. However, how do I apply this doubling relation? I do not see that yet.

Comment: They are _simple_ poles here. In general, the functions must have the same principal part in the poles, the same residue just says the coefficient of $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ is the same. But for simple poles, that's the only thing in the principal part. The doubling relation and the maximum principle together  show that $h$ must be constant. I'm not going into details before the homework must have been turned in.

Comment: “principal part” is the “Hauptteil der Laurentreihe”? I will keep working on it, that is fair :-)

Comment: Yep, Hauptteil is right.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it now. The doubling relation implies that $h(2z)$ is the mean of the values at $z$ and $z+\pi/2$. Therefore, if $2z$ is on the circle, it cannot be the maximum, if $h$ is not a constant. See [my solution](http://chaos.stw-bonn.de/users/mu/uploads/2014-01-21/11-2-Martin.pdf).

Comment: Right. As long as the radius of the circle is large enough that both $z$ and $z + \frac{\pi}{2}$ lie inside the circle when $2z$ lies on the boundary, which requires a radius $\geqslant \pi$ (if $z+\frac{\pi}{2}$ lies on the boundary, we still know the absolute value there is not larger than in $2z$, that suffices).

Comment: Instead of arguing with the difference to $h(2z)$, it is more common to just say $\lvert 2h(2z)\rvert = \left\lvert h(z) + h\left(z+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right\rvert \leqslant \lvert h(z)\rvert + \left\lvert h\left(z+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right\rvert \Rightarrow \lvert h(2z)\rvert \leqslant \max \left\{ \lvert h(z)\rvert, \left\lvert h\left(z+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right\rvert\right\}$, which for a radius $> \pi$ by the maximum principle implies that $h$ is constant.